# TFS Server Side Plugin started twice

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've implemented a simple WorkItemChangedEventHandler for TFS 2015.

On my TFS 2015 Express test installation, the event handler gets **instantiated twice**. The first instance is created right after the TFS recognizes the *BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename* as a consequence of the new build. The second instance is created right after accessing the database for the first time.

Given this source code (note, only the constructor is relevant):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;

namespace MyFirstTfsPlugin
{
    public class TfsTriggerConfluenceUpdateOnWorkItemChanged : ISubscriber
    {
        public TfsTriggerConfluenceUpdateOnWorkItemChanged()
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", $"New Plugin Instance Created with Hash {GetHashCode()}");
        }

        public string Name => "WorkItemChangedEventHandler";

        public SubscriberPriority Priority => SubscriberPriority.Normal;

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes() => new[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
            IVssRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs,
            out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage,
            out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following events logged:

```
Information 09.03.2017 17:37:16 TFS Services        9002    None    The application is being shutdown for the following reason: BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename
Information 09.03.2017 17:37:23 TFS Services        0       None    New Plugin Instance Created with Hash 44661510
Information 09.03.2017 17:37:24 TFS Services        9001    None    Application Request Processing Started
Information 09.03.2017 17:37:58 MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS    17137   Server  Starting up database 'Tfs_DefaultCollection'.
Information 09.03.2017 17:37:58 TFS Services        0       None    New Plugin Instance Created with Hash 27996961
```

**Is this a bug in TFS 2015 or do I miss something?**

Comment: When an event comes through is your code called twice?

Comment: Event is only fired once. Thanks for the hint. However, I have to redesign my event handler because it needs to create a background thread to trigger a deferred update process. No good to have two such threads running at the same time.

Comment: Why not implement this as a service hook instead of a server-side plugin?

Comment: @freefall Do you mean the server side plugin is actually triggered once? You may install this existing plugin to see whether it will be triggered twice: https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator

Comment: @Cece - MSFT Your solution looks very comprehensive and versatile. However, my approach is to add kind of a quiet period after each work item change and to export all changes to our wiki after the quiet period has expired.

Comment: @Daniel Mann For the same reason, I gonna go for a server side plugin rather than for a service hook. Thanks for your suggestion, anyway.

Comment: However, it's a matter of fact that the ISubscriber class is instantiated twice. I'd still consider this kind of an unwanted behavior.

Comment: @freefall, I mean you can try the existing server side plugin to see whether you would get the same behaviour. Then we can find whether the issue from your code side or TFS side.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Given the simplicity of the provided code, I doubt that the issue is likely to come from my code site, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code on my side, and found the event log wrote "New Plugin Instance Created with Hash xxxxxx" from time to time, not just twice (Sorry that I couldn't find out why this happen).

But if adding EventLog.WriteEntry in ProcessEvent, the behavior is correct. When a work item is changed, there will be one and only one entry in Event log:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;

namespace MyFirstTfsPlugin
{
    public class TfsTriggerConfluenceUpdateOnWorkItemChanged : ISubscriber
    {
               //public TfsTriggerConfluenceUpdateOnWorkItemChanged()
    //{
    //    EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services 1", $"New Plugin Instance Created with Hash {GetHashCode()}");
    //}

        public string Name => "WorkItemChangedEventHandler";

        public SubscriberPriority Priority => SubscriberPriority.Normal;

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes() => new[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
            IVssRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs,
            out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage,
            out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services 2", $"workitem Created with Hash {GetHashCode()}");
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]